# Lucene updateDocument speed

Tags: optimization, lucene

I am concurrently indexing via Lucene approx. 5k documents which each has approx. size 20kB and I need to update them frequently via updateDocument method.

I am using NRT where may up to 50 threads update documents. Commit is done in separate thread after 100 updates/inserts or 10 minutes timeout.

So far average duration of each document update is 1 seconds with eventuall peaks (80 seconds, need to analyze the concrete document).

Can somebody advise me what policy/optimization I should use to speed document updating?

Comment: You may want to look at the [NRT](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/NearRealtimeSearch) support if you need efficient, fast updates. A lot of work has been done in this area the past few years.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the issue here.  I believe NRT search intends to improve liveness, making updates immediately available to search.  It sounds like the problem here is the update simply take too long to complete, with the load of 5000 updates completing in about 1.5 hours.  Is that correct?

Comment: 1 second is very long for updating one document unless your analysis chain is very expensive. Can you profile? What is the bottleneck?

Comment: You might be able to improve speed if you don't commit on each update but have a background task issuing commits on a regular basis.

Comment: Sending some more specific details after my investigation. I am using NRT when updating of the documents is done concurrently up to 50 threads. I commit items after 100 documents or 10 minutes timeout in separate thread. The overall performance is 1 second per document, but sometimes one documents takes up 80 seconds (I need to analyze it deeply). I was wondering whether such slow update might be caused by wrong policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that NRT flush in memory documents when application asks for up-to-date reader which wasn't beneficial from indexing perspective.

Switched to normal indexing and also change flush policy to be handled by item count instead of memory, because bigger documents caused frequent flushes.